# How to configure two nic cards interfaces placed in separate machines having same network in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, network-adapter

I am working on nic cards configuration, i have two nic cards (sfc 9021 and sfc 9020) placed in two separate machines that are on a common gateway/router. One interface of each nic is connected (point-point)to other nic's interface using Ethernet cable.

What I'm doing is configuring these to a same subnet, like machines is on network `192.168.x.x`, I'm assigning ip's to nic like this:

```
nic1: sudo ifconfig interface1 192.168.9.x  
nic2: sudo ifconfig interface1 192.168.9.x
```

But these interfaces are unable to ping each other, in **`sudo nmap 192.168.9.0/24`** machine only shows its own interface.

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 on machine 1 and 18.04 on machine 2.

if any excess information required please suggest in comments.

Comment: Is `interface1` the actual name you used in `ifconfig` command or just a placeholder? You should use the actual device name like `eth1` or similar.
What devices are shown if you type `ifconfig -a`?
Also, in Ubuntu, network adapters are configured using Network Manager. Network Manager settings might overwrite what you have set with `ifconfig`. Probably the easiest method would be to use the Network Manager GUI to configure these adapters.

Comment: @raj  interface1 is just a place holder,moreover, i used the real interface name as ifconfig params

Comment: And does `ifconfig -a` correctly show that interface with the IP address you configured?

Comment: Yes, ip can be seen for respective interfaces

Comment: Then I'll suggest two things: 1) turn off the firewall if you are using any; 2) check if you are using the correct cable. When connecting directly one NIC to other NIC (without a switch), you should generally use a cross-over Ethernet cable instead of a regular "straight" one.

Comment: actually machines are on a remote location, cable which is used is spf+10g ethernet cable

Comment: And firewall is disabled

Comment: The category of a cable is not what is important, the pin layout of the cable is. If your network cards cannot automatically recognize that the pins are inverted, you need a crossover cable. Install the `ethtool` package and check if the `ethtool` command will show physically connected status for your device. If not, you should change the cable to crossover cable. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable

Comment: @raj , sir i have already checked the interface connection status using ethtool and the status is coming connected.However i shall see the cable recommendation from you.